# When I started HAProxy under Windows Server, I got the following error

Tags: windows, rabbitmq, haproxy

haproxy.exe -f haproxy.cfg -d
When I run HAProxy, I get an error:
'''

```
Available polling systems :
       poll : pref=200,  test result OK
     select : pref=150,  test result FAILED
Total: 2 (1 usable), will use poll.

Available filters :
        [SPOE] spoe
        [CACHE] cache
        [FCGI] fcgi-app
        [COMP] compression
        [TRACE] trace
Using poll() as the polling mechanism.
[NOTICE]   (1036) : haproxy version is 2.4.0-6cbbecf
[ALERT]    (1036) : Starting proxy warelucent: cannot bind socket (Address already in use) [0.0.0.0:5672]
[ALERT]    (1036) : [haproxy.main()] Some protocols failed to start their listeners! Exiting.
```

'''

In the meantime, no other services are running, and I have the RabbitMQ service open.
My haproxy.cfg file is as follows：
'''

```
#logging options
global
    log 127.0.0.1 local0 info
    maxconn 1500
    daemon
    quiet
    nbproc 20

defaults
    log global
    mode tcp
    #if you set mode to tcp,then you nust change tcplog into httplog
    option tcplog
    option dontlognull
    retries 3
    option redispatch
    maxconn 2000
    timeout connect 10s
     timeout client 10s
     timeout server 10s 
#front-end IP for consumers and producters

listen warelucent
    bind 0.0.0.0:5672
    #配置TCP模式
    mode tcp
    #balance url_param userid
    #balance url_param session_id check_post 64
    #balance hdr(User-Agent)
    #balance hdr(host)
    #balance hdr(Host) use_domain_only
    #balance rdp-cookie
    #balance leastconn
    #balance source //ip
    #简单的轮询
    balance roundrobin
        server one  1.1.1.1:5672 check inter 5000 rise 2 fall 2
        server two  2.2.2.2:5672 check inter 5000 rise 2 fall 2
        server three    3.3.3.3:5672 check inter 5000 rise 2 fall 2
listen stats
    bind 127.0.0.1:8100
    mode http
    option httplog
    stats enable
    stats uri /rabbitmq-stats
    stats refresh 5s
```

'''

Most of the Internet is due to the version, but I checked the official website, the version is the latest, and I also started the RabbitMQ service, so I don't know where the error is at present

Answer (score 0):

```
(Address already in use) [0.0.0.0:5672]
```

it means that the port `5672` (RabbitMQ is already in use. Most likely you have a rabbitmq node running in that machine.

So just change the HA-PROXY port.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will change my configuration file port